# problems with sed script using curly brace block with homebrew gnu sed

Tags: macos, sed, gnu

I am having trouble with an old sed script that I dug out of the archives that worked fine years ago, but now is not.

The old script was complex, having multiple substitutions between the curly braces, but even really dumbed down to a single substitution, I can not get it to work now.

I am attempting to use it with home-brew gnu-sed on Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan, but had the same trouble on debian as well, so it seems like a gnu sed specific issue. It works with regular OS X /usr/bin/sed, but not with gnu sed which I would prefer to use for the sake of portability.

Does gnu sed need different flags to allow the use of the curly braces or something else along those lines? in all cases below the sed command links to /usr/local/bin/gsed on the OS X machine. I suppose I could just use OS X sed, but that wouldn't help me on a linux box should I need to use the script there.

Thanks.

The error I get is

```
sed: file script_file line 3: extra characters after command
```

Here is my simple two line data file.

```
[[aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]]
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Here is the correct output assuming the script ran successfully.

```
[[bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb]]
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Here is the sed script that does not work when stored in a file.

```
/\[\[.*\]\]/{
s/a/b/g
}
```

Here is the command I am using to run it.

```
sed -f script_file data_file
```

If I eliminate the curly braces in the file it works, but then I can't apply multiple substitutions to the same pattern space. Here is a version of the script file that works without a problem.

```
 /\[\[.*\]\]/s/a/b/g
```

if I put everything on the command line including the curly braces, it also works.

```
sed '/\[\[.*\]\]/{s/a/b/g}' data_file
```

This one also works with stdin data as well.

What do I need to do to get the multi-line curly brace block script file version to work properly with gnu sed?

Comment: Works for me. I have `GNU sed version 4.2.1`

Comment: Works for me too with same version and Ubuntu 11.04. Check your file for unwanted characters: `cat -A script_file`.

Comment: Works with sed and gsed (GNU sed) from Solaris 11 too.

Comment: figured it out. original sed file needed conversion with dos2unix. Works fine now. The problem was a file format migration problem between the old an new system. Cyrus was right about unwanted characters in script_file. Thanks.